# Count based on subset of data

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a join to a table and I want to include all users who have a record after a certain date, but to only include records after another date in the count.

Here is my SQL :

```
select a.userid, count(ce.codeentryid)
from [account] a
inner join [profile] p
on a.userid = p.userid
inner join codesentered ce
on a.userid = ce.userid  and ce.entrydate > '2011-01-01 00:00:00'
where a.camp = 0
group by a.userid
order by a.userid
```

So here I want to view a list of all users who have entered a code after 1st Jan 2011, but to only include in the count codes entered after 1st Jan 2013.  How would I do this?

EDIT : So this would give me all users who have entered a code after 01/01/2011, but only include codes entered after 01/01/2013 in the count?

```
select a.userid, count(CASE WHEN ce.entrydate > '2013-01-01 00:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
from [account] a
inner join [profile] p
on a.userid = p.userid
inner join codesentered ce
on a.userid = ce.userid  and ce.entrydate > '2011-01-01 00:00:00'
where a.camp = 0
group by a.userid
order by a.userid
```

Comment: Please share sample data & required output. I am not able to understand your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the date condition from the `ON` clause, and use this in the `SELECT` clause instead of `COUNT(ce.codeentryid)`:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ce.entrydate > '2011-01-01 00:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: COUNT(CASE WHEN ce.entrydate > '2011-01-01 00:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense, because using two dates is redundant.  Unless I assume that you want users whose first count is after 2011-01-01 and then only count what happens after 2013-01-01.

If that is what you want, then use a `having` clause:

```
select a.userid, sum(CASE WHEN ce.entrydate > '2013-01-01 00:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
from [account] a inner join
     [profile] p
     on a.userid = p.userid inner join
     codesentered ce
     on a.userid = ce.userid
where a.camp = 0
group by a.userid
having min(ce.entrydate) > '2011-01-01 00:00:00'
order by a.userid;
```

Note that `count(CASE WHEN ce.entrydate > '2013-01-01 00:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` is the same as `count(*)`.  `count()` counts non-null values.  Use `sum()` instead.